# How to fetch values from 2 tables based on the first table's values

Tags: module, magento-1, model

I have developed a custom module which includes three DB tables. I need to fetch values from one table and then based on that value fetch values from second table.

For ex below is the table description:

`**deal_offers**  : entity_id | deal_name | deal_discount`

`**deal_products** : deal_id | product_id`

In my observer, I am getting `product_id` value. Now for say `product_id`, what I want to achieve is

1. First, fetch `deal_id` value from table `deal_products`, using the value
   of product_id
2. Next, fetch `deal_discount` value, using `deal_id` which is the
   **entity_id** in table `deal_offers`

I have defined `<entities>` in my config.xml for these two tables, but not getting success 
in achieving the desired result using `Mage::getModel('module/model')` method in my observer.

Please Help

Thanks
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try using following code snippet, it's an example of inner join operation of two table.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('module/modelB')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$product_id);
$collection->getSelect()
    ->join('deal_offers', 'main_table.entity_id=deal_offers.deal_id',array('deal_name','deal_discount'));
```

Comment: this `$collection = Mage::getModel('module/modelB')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$product_id);` gives me all records. Need to use foreach loop to get a single record.

Comment: That's why there's the second row with JOIN. SQL query language allows to join two tables based on information fetched from either one of them.

Comment: It says `Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento_18\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816` when I add `addFieldToFilter('product_id',$product_id)`

Comment: `$collection = Mage::getModel('module/modelB')->getCollection()`, gives me array of products and I do not seem to apply filter on this.

Comment: Paste your config.xml please.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> $collection = Mage::getModel('module/modelB')->getCollection() ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$product_id)->getFirstItem();